# Configuring phpmyadmin in palapa web server

Tags: android, phpmyadmin, webserver

I recently downloaded `palapa web server` in my Infinix Hot 2 to test an android application which requires a database connection. However, when I tried downloading `phpmyadmin` from `palapa web server DB server settings`.

it always gave me the following error:

> `Install failed with error:http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/phpmyadmin/phpMyAdmin/4.1.14.1/phpMyAdmin-4.1.14.1-english.php?download&failedmirror=jaist.dl.sourceforge.net`.

So I decided to download `phpmyadmin` manually from `www.phpmyadmin.net`. I unzipped the file to `/pws/phpmyadmin` directory and tried giving the folder several names but when I went to `http://127.0.0.1:9999/phpmydmin` in my Chrome browser, it only showed me the files in `phpmyadmin` folder. I would really like some help to get `phpmyadmin` working. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Strange story. PWS comes with phpadmin already. Look at the phpadmin directory in the pws directory.

Comment: it only contains `index.php` which tells me that `phpmyadmin` is not installed and that I have to go to `DB Server settings` to install it. Maybe version 2.1.1 doesn't come with `phpmyadmin` or something

Comment: Then go to those settings and install! Whats the problem with that? Otherwise you should uninstall/install again. They belong to the core tools.

Comment: As I said in the description, when I try downloading using the settings it gives me an error

Comment: Sorry i had not unsderstood what you did with those settings. Well then uninstall and try again. The app just will ask you then to install the 'core'.

Comment: Hey, I downloaded `phpmyadmin` using `ksweb` then moved the folder to `/pws/phpmyadmin` directory and `phpmyadmin` worked though am having problems with logging in

Answer (score 1):

The reason the manually downloaded `phpmyadmin` was not working was because there was no `index.php` :)

I manually downloaded `phpmyadmin` that my `pws` required that is `phpmyadmin-4.1.14.1-english.zip` and extracted the files to `/pws/phpmyadmin`. then I cleared browsing history and cache and site data from my `Chrome` browser and `phpmyadmin` was up and running.